# subdomain redirect to folder without changing the URL

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, subdomain

When visiting subdomain.domain.nl I'm forwarded to domain.nl/subdomain but... what I want is not to change the URL.

I've got the following code in my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.nl$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.nl/subdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

So when visiting subdomain.domain.nl I want to be invisibly forwarded to the folder called subdomain in www.domain.nl/subdomain but not change the URL.

I've checked several topics here but still can't find a suitable answer for my problem, anyone?

Kind regards, Twan

Comment: You can't do an internal redirect across domains.  So this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `http://` or `https://` in the beginning of your `RewriteRule`'s target, it assumes you want a 302 redirect. Thus it redirects the browser and the browser's URL address bar changes.

If the vhosts for `subdomain.domain.nl` and `www.domain.nl` have the same document root, then you can just remove the host part from the target:

```
RewriteRule ^ /subdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And it won't redirect. Otherwise, you can try using the `[P]` flag to internally proxy.